# If I use a separate physical server for the DB, do I still need to install it on the app server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using a Postgres database with Rails. Postgres on a different physical server.

I can't do a bundle install on the app server that has the Rails app since Postgres doesn't exist on it.

Is it required to install postgres even on the app servers (even though the app's database.yml will connect to a different server anyway)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have problems with installing `pg` gem. If so, then no, you don't need to install the postgres database server on your app server host. But for the gem, you need the postgresql development headers.

On ubuntu, for example, you can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

And then `gem install pg` or `bundle install` should succeed.